# Why can one remove/rename open files in Linux?

Tags: linux, language-agnostic, filesystems

I learned that open files can *not* be removed/renamed in Windows but *can* be removed/renamed in Linux (by default). I think I understand the reasons of the Windows behaviour.

Now I wonder *why* Linux allows remame/remove of open files ? What was the design rationale behind this decision ? What are the use cases when one need it ?

Answer (score 6):

the difference is that linux works on file handles rather than file names. as long as the file handle is valid you can read and write to it.

renaming a file in linux does not alter the file handle.

one very interesting use case is to delete temp files after opening them.
this makes it impossible for every other process to access this file, while the process that owns the file handle can still read and write.

Comment: That doesn't make accessing the deleted file impossible, just more complicated.

Comment: @jlliagre: I'm not sure to be honest. You might be right depending on the context. i.e.: Could be that this works in Linux and POSIX semantics do not specify anything about this. etc.

Comment: I suggest to read Wikipage on [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), and I think *file inode* is a more precise word than *file handle* (which makes me think of `<stdio.h>`'s `FILE`)

Comment: Accessing a deleted still open file is easy with OSes implementing some sort of /proc filesystem. This includes Linux, Solaris, AIX and likely others. This is non portable though a not specified by POSIX.